# private whois but still list email-address?

Tags: dns, email, whois

I tried Googling it, but I couldn't find an answer.

I would like private whois, meaning I wouldn't want to display my home address etc.

However, I still would want to list email-address.

Comment: Every private whois service I've seen *does* list an e-mail address, under their own domain, which gets forwarded to you. Is it that you want to provide a custom domain that goes straight to you? That would probably be seen as missing the point a bit.

Comment: @Su' can you show me an example of such private whois's?

Comment: @ub3rst4r pretty much covers it below. (Though I personally disagree about not worrying.) There are some standalone domain privacy services, but whoever you registered your domain with probably offers their own implementation of it already, so no point dealing with anyone else unless really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Under ICANN's policy for domain names, they all must list the owner of the domain names:

- First and last name
- Address (including city, country, postal code, etc)
- Email address
- Phone and/or fax number

However, some websites (such as GoDaddy and Name.com) are able to use their information instead for about $10/yr. The problem with the email address that usually use is it is a forwarded email address. For example: A WHOIS will list example.com@protecteddomainservices.com but emails that are sent to it are redirected to joe.blow@hotmail.com (some registrars also have spam filters that emails must go through first in order to be redirected). To be honest, I wouldn't worry about having your own information in the domain WHOIS because you have to remember the millions (if not billions) of people that have listed their information as well.